# Android deep link, open web browser when link not supported

Tags: java, android-deep-link

I have created an intent-filter that uses this:

```
<action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
```

and have registered a URL to open my app when clicked. This works as intended until I try and detect a link I do not support. Say I do some more processing in my main Activity, determine the link is not supported, and try to launch the web browser. This is what I am using:

```
Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(launchUrl));
activity.startActivity(browserIntent);
```

Now the problem here is this link is still registered to open my app. It essentially creates a routing loop where it continuously opens my app every time I try and launch to a browser. Is there a way to force open in a browser and not allow my app to intercept it a 2nd time?

Comment: did you got a answer?

Comment: @Peter It looks too late but if you're still looking for an answer, check out this answer -> https://stackoverflow.com/a/58801285/1930006