# Android App link - Open a url from app in browser without triggering App Link

Tags: android, deep-linking, android-app-links

I have enabled App linking in my application. It works fine. But in my application there are some scenarios where i cannot handle the incoming url. In those cases i want to redirect that url to the default browser in the device.

Currently what i have tried doing is using intents to open browser with the url, but it again redirects to my app itself. The app link is of the format ->

```
https://<domain>/<prefix>/<params>
```

so depending on the params, i would like to either handle the app link in the app itself or redirect it to the default browser. Below is the code i tried to open the browser with the above url

```
val browserIntent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(appLinkModel.url))
browserIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_APP_BROWSER)
browserIntent.resolveActivity(packageManager)?.let {
    startActivity(browserIntent)
}
```

I tried excluding the addCategory() line but the results are the same. Either the app crashes(hence the resolveActivity()), or app opens itself in a loop.

**WHAT I WANT TO DO**

So what i want to do is redirect the url to the default browser(or show a chooser **WITHOUT** my app in it), without triggering the app link again and again. So is this possible?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

```
String data = "example.com/your_url?param=some_param";
Intent defaultBrowser = Intent.makeMainSelectorActivity(Intent.ACTION_MAIN, Intent.CATEGORY_APP_BROWSER);
defaultBrowser.setData(data);
startActivity(defaultBrowser);
```

this technique (using makeMainSelectorActivity) will force the link to open in the device's default browser

Note - [makeMainSelectorActivity](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#makeMainSelectorActivity(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) only works for API level 15 and above.

If you need to support API levels lower than 15, you could try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34957893/847575) hack

For Android 13 (API level 33) and above a MAIN Action selector may not work when sending a VIEW intent as Android enforces the intent matching the intent filter. The following approach should work for API level 33 (and also 15+):

```
val emptyBrowserIntent = Intent()
    .setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)
    .addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_BROWSABLE)
    .setData(Uri.fromParts("http", "", null))
val targetIntent = Intent()
    .setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)
    .addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_BROWSABLE)
    .setData(targetUri)
    .setSelector(emptyBrowserIntent)
startActivity(targetIntent)
```

Comment: It working fine on android 12 and below, but not working on android 13. on android 13, It throw ActivityNotFoundException.

Comment: See also https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/243678703

Comment: In Android 13, the app throws an exception: ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] dat=https://... sel=act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.APP_BROWSER]} }. See https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/243678703. In my opinion, we can indeed use a try-catch block to catch the exception and then proceed with opening the webview.

Answer (score 8):

In `Kotlin`, try using [makeMainSelectorActivity](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#makeMainSelectorActivity(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) :

```
val defaultBrowser = Intent.makeMainSelectorActivity(Intent.ACTION_MAIN, Intent.CATEGORY_APP_BROWSER)
defaultBrowser.data = Uri.parse("https://yoururl.com/")
startActivity(defaultBrowser)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58800240/android-app-link-open-a-url-from-app-in-browser-without-triggering-app-link"));
        Intent chooseIntent = Intent.createChooser(intent, "Choose from below");
        startActivity(chooseIntent);
```

This will open all the installed web browsers from which user can choose!

Comment: I have already tried this. This just redirects back to my app itself because of the App linking.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, we can't exclude any certain URL, since Android doesn't provide that option.

But you can handle using path prefix.

```
// To handle:
http://myhost.com/v/page1?id=123
// To exclude:
http://myhost.com/v/page2?id=123
```

then in manifiest

```
<data android:scheme="http"
      android:host="myhost.com"
      android:pathPrefix="/v/page1" />
```

Comment: Sorry. I cannot use this. Because the in the url the only change is the "param" portion. And based on the params i have to decide whether to handle it in the app or browser.

Comment: Try opening in custom chrome tab