# How do I open the deep link in mobile browser rather than mobile app in react native

Tags: react-native, deep-linking, react-native-linking

What I am trying to do is opening a deep link in mobile browse (Not in app). Deeplinking is all set up, all the links with specific domains are opening/navigating into app opened from any where else. Now here is a scenario that there are some particular links with same domain (I set up deeplinking for), I want to open that in browser because I don't have any view to show for that link in my app so I want them open in browser.

I have identified the links but when I opened these links via Linking.openUrl it navigates me to the app.

```
  if (lowerUrl.includes(PostType.NO_DEEP_LINK)) {
  Linking.openURL(lowerUrl);
  return null;
}
```

Is there any method I can specify the Linking method to open url in mobile browser not in app although the url has a same domain that is setup for deep linkg.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution 1#**

The best possible solution for that can be using `android:pathPattern` in android manifest. Basically you have to provide path pattern (a sort regex) to match the valid links.

Documentation for that can be found here.
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/data-element

**Solution # 2**

One has to make [RN Native Module](https://reactnative.dev/docs/native-modules-android) and instead Linking.openURL(lowerUrl) to handle this kind of scenario.

To make browser native module one can take help from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72392915/7151449).
This solution doesn't work with devices which lacks google play services like Kindle Fire, etc